# Oracle Package Body PLS-00113: End Identifier must match

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT" IS

    PROCEDURE PRC_SHARINGLOSSAGREEMENTNAME (
        I_SF_SUBSIDIARY_ID IN NUMBER,
        I_RVP_SCENARIO_ID IN NUMBER,
        I_RVP_CALC_REPORTING_DATE IN DATE,
        I_CURRENCY_ISO_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
        o_VariableResult OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

END "PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT";
```

When I try to define the package body I receive the error:

> PLS-00113: END identifier 'PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT' must match
>   'PKG_Rvp_Calc_Report' at line 1, column 15

The names are the same and they are all upper case too!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT" IS

    PROCEDURE PRC_SHARINGLOSSAGREEMENTNAME (
        I_SF_SUBSIDIARY_ID IN NUMBER,
        I_RVP_SCENARIO_ID IN NUMBER,
        I_RVP_CALC_REPORTING_DATE IN DATE,
        I_CURRENCY_ISO_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
        o_VariableResult OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
    IS
        baseIsoCode CONSTANT VARCHAR2(3)    := 'EUR';
        rateDate DATE;
    BEGIN
        OPEN o_VariableResult FOR
        select * from dual;

    END; --Procedure

END "PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT";
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure the `create` statement doesn't look like this instead? `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "PKG_Rvp_Calc_Report" IS`... That would generate the error message you posted.

Comment: I suggest not using the quotes (") at all, so your object (package) names will always be uppercase regardless of how they appear in your `create` statements.

Comment: The error message clearly suggests that you have at least one place where you used `"PKG_Rvp_Calc_Report"` instead of  `"PKG_RVP_CALC_REPORT"`. You should follow GriffeyDog's advice and simply never use double quotes in SQL or PL/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running this on a local database.  I rebooted and I was able to run the exact same statement successfully.  It looks like a bug in Oracle.